# Difference between secondary analysis and data mining

Tags: methods, statistics, data-mining, spss

I am trying to extract some consumption patterns of certain demographic groups from large multidimensional datasets built for other purposes. I am using clustering and regression analysis with manual methods (SPSS). Is this considered to be secondary analysis or data mining? I understand the difference between statistical analysis and data mining, but in this case seems to be sort of in between... Thanks

Comment: I have never heard "secondary analysis". What is the definition?

Comment: Are you trying to ask what is the interacting role of statistics and data mining? Please be more specific with your question because "secondary analysis" is confusing term here.

Comment: Sure, I'm new in the area and thought would be a fairly common concept: "Secondary analysis involves the use of existing data, collected for the purposes of a prior study, in order to pursue a research interest which is distinct from that of the original work; this may be a new research question or an alternative perspective on the original question. In this respect, secondary analysis differs from systematic reviews and meta-analyses of qualitative studies which aim instead to compile and assess the evidence relating to a common concern or area of practice." (Heaton, 1998)

Comment: That is unrelated to data-mining itself. "Secondary analysis" in this sense means that the data was collected for "primary" research project A, but then was analyzed *again* for "secondary" project B with a very different objective that was not originally planned. Maybe much later maybe by different people. Fairly common in medicine if you want to avoid the cost of doing the experiments yourself, and someone else has published suitable data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Anony-Mousse, but I don't understand why this is unrelated to data mining if by definition you can use multiple datasets to discover new patterns? This technique is common in medicine but also in social research in general (e.g., marketing, education, etc.) and involves data preprocessing, modeling/analysis and interpretation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Secondary analysis" means that the data was collected for "primary" research project A, but then was analyzed *again* for "secondary" project B with a very different objective that was not originally planned. Maybe much later maybe by different people. Fairly common in medicine if you want to avoid the cost of doing the experiments yourself, and someone else has published suitable data.

A theoretical example:

1. Research group A does a clinical trial on drug B, and measures body mass, and insuline levels.
2. Data is published, for both the study group (with drug B) and the control group (without drug B).
3. ... ten years later ...
4. Research group C wants to know if there is a correlation between body mass and insuline levels. They do not care about drug B, so they only look at the control group. They join the data with the data of many other groups instead of doing own experiments.

This is not a "meta" study, because they disregard any results with respect to drug B. They do not use the results of group A, only their data, for a *different purpose*. Since this is secondary use of the data, it is called "secondary analysis".

The analysis could be as simple as computing correlation - something usually not considered to be "data mining" (you do not *search*, nor use *advanced* statistics) but tradational statistical hypothesis testing.

Comment: OK, but let's say that I want to predict e.g. intention to re-purchase using a number of public surveys, so I normalise and pool meaningful variables and then use correlation, clustering, and regression analysis (together) to identify the best predictors. This would be considered secondary analysis or data mining?

Comment: They are *orthogonal* concepts. Something can be both, or neither. One is about *purpose* of the data, and the other is about the *methods* applied.

Comment: Just what I needed to know